# Typescript sync function works locally but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've been struggling with this error for 2 weeks now.

My project has an "Update changes" button that should be disabled if no changes have been done in the form (that retrieves a complex object item). This assertion must be done at every change in the form, so that if the user changes something but then puts the old value again, the button should also go back to disabled.

I have a synchronous Typescript function that evaluates if two provided objects have equal properties, and the code goes as following:

```
export function isEqual<T>(oldObj: T, newObj: T): boolean {
  let assertion: boolean = true;

  if (oldObj instanceof Object && newObj instanceof Object) {
    const keys = Object.keys(oldObj) as (keyof T)[];

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const key = keys[i];

      if (oldObj[key] instanceof Object && !(oldObj[key] instanceof Array)) {
        if (!isEqual<any>(oldObj[key], newObj[key])) {
          assertion = false;
          break;
        }
      } else if (oldObj[key] instanceof Array) {
        for (let j = 0; j < (oldObj[key] as unknown as any[]).length; j++) {
          if (
            !isEqual(
              (oldObj[key] as unknown as any[])[j],
              (newObj[key] as unknown as any[])[j]
            )
          ) {
            assertion = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (oldObj[key] !== newObj[key]) {
          assertion = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    assertion = oldObj === newObj;
  }

  return assertion;
}
```

This function is embedded in a `useMemo` React hook, that listens to every change in the `newObj`. The function works perfect locally but as soon as I deploy it to either beta/prod environments, it only works *partially*. On some items the assertion is done correctly but on others the assertion is misscalculated, either by not listening to a change or by not detecting a value returned to its old equal.

Things I have tried, without success:

- Disabling `react_dev_tools`.
- Using a hardcoded function instead of a generic one (i.e. evaluating the specific fields of my object one by one).
- Transforming the function into a Javascript one.
- Running the app in incognito mode.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal

Comment: "On some items the assertion is done correctly but on others the assertion is misscalculated, either by not listening to a change or by not detecting a value returned to its old equal."

-- Sounds like the issue might be the code that uses this function rather than the function.

Comment: @ Fralle It can well be (especially since I tested the function with all necessary assertions) but how does that explain why it works locally but not when deployed? Keep in mind that the function works not only alone but when used by the component.

@ LeoDog896 I've tested the module but so far it is not giving me any better results, I will keep trying though